# Performance problem with 500 products in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, performance, woocommerce, product

I manage my customer website and he has 500 products to import in wooocommerce in wordpress
When I delete all the product, all the whole wordpress website recomes faster and when I import them again, it's very slow...
I viewed that wordpress load all the database on each page even if don't needed
I tested on a contact page and its the same
how to enforce wordpress to load only in database what needed in the page ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your customer's website need a caching plugin like WP rocket. You may also check the overall performance of the website using [Google Pagespeed Insights](https://pagespeed.web.dev)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).